# How to call @EventHandler during the test of axon?

Tags: axon

I have the following flow:

```
@CommandHandler
public PaymentsAggregate(RegisterPaymentCommand command){...}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(PaymentRegisteredEvent event){...}

@EventHandler
public void on(PaymentRegisteredEvent event){
   paymentRepository.save(event.getPayment());
   if(someCondition)
      commandGateway.send(new ReturnPaymentCommand(...));
}

@CommandHandler
public void handle(ReturnPaymentCommand command){...}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(PaymentReturnedEvent event){...}

@EventHandler
public void on(PaymentReturnedEvent event){...}
```

I want to test my `RegisterPaymentCommand`, sometimes it fires the `ReturnPaymentCommand`. So, in my `expectEvents` I have `PaymentRegisteredEvent` and `PaymentReturnedEvent`. But I realized that the `@EventSourcingHandler` method of `PaymentRegisteredEvent` is never fired while testing so `ReturnPaymentCommand` is never called.

What can I do or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing 2 types of testing here.

1. Aggregate test

For this type of test, Axon Framework provides the `AggregateTestFixture` for helping you. As you are probably already doing, those tests are in a form of given/when/then and should validate if the flow of commands and events are the correct and expected one.

for example:

```
aggregateFixture.given(new AnyEvent())
                .when(new AnyCommand())
                .expectEvents(new ExpectedEvent());
```

or `expectException`, `expectNoEvents`, etc.

2. Message Handler Component test

This component should be unit tested like any other component. For this, you can simply mock whatever you need (usually your repository), and test when a method of given component is called, that you do what you need to do (save/update/delete an entry for example)

for example:

```
@Test
void testAnyEventHandlerMethod() {
    messageHandler.on(new AnyEvent());
    verify(myMockedRepository).save(entityDerivedFromEvent());
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your answer. Yes, I´m using AggregateTestFixture, but what can I do if I need to test that the call to my  RegisterPaymentCommand calls the ReturnPaymentCommand?  Is it not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "call to my RegisterPaymentCommand calls the ReturnPaymentCommand"? What is the flow/behaviour you want to test?

Comment: My EventHandler invoke other command

`@EventHandler
public void on(PaymentRegisteredEvent event){
   paymentRepository.save(event.getPayment());
   if(someCondition)
      commandGateway.send(new ReturnPaymentCommand(...));
}`

So, when my RegisterPaymentCommand is fired, its EventHandler invokes ReturnPaymentCommand.

Comment: And I want to test something like: `fixture. when(new RegisterPaymentCommand()).expectSuccessfulHandlerExecution()
            .expectEvents(new PaymentRegisteredEvent (), new PaymentReturnedEvent ());`.

Comment: In the first case, for the event handler, you can just `verify` the `commandGateway` was called. For the second case, if that command handler creates 2 new events, it is fine to use the `expectEvents` with a list of expected events. Nothing wrong with that.